# how to compile libgit2 and create static lib used by xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, libgit2

How to compile libgit2 and create static lib used by xcode.
I don't know how to use LLVM to compile libgit2 to get a static '.a' file.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake, it's libgit2 http://libgit2.github.com/api.html

Comment: thx， I have solved this by using another tool

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C bindings' README has instructions on how to use libgit2 with an iOS app.

https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git#inclusion-in-ios-projects

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by [this tool](https://github.com/Eonil/libgit2-make-ios). Very helpful.